# for linear Operators is it true that $(A^*)^{-1}=I$, whrere $I$ is the neutral element?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

If A is a linear operator between Hilbert spaces. Is the following statement true?

> $(A^*)^{-1}A=I$, where $I$ is the neutral element so that $A^{-1}A=I$

Comment: It isn't true in finite dimension, therefore no.

Answer (score 4):

Not true. A counter-example is $iA$ where $A$ is an invertible self-adjoint operator.

Answer (score 3):

We have $(A^*)^{-1}A=I \iff (A^*)^{-1}=A^{-1} \iff A^*=A \iff A $ is self-adjoint.